# Failed to download repository information ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-center

I am a new user of Linux migrating from Windows. I do not know much about Ubuntu. I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 version. At start, Software Center was working, but now Software Center is not working. It is showing this error:

> Failed to download repository information. Check your internet network

Please tell me the solution of this problem, and also give me some useful tips % tricks about linux.

Comment: Can I use any other method to install software? I mean If I downloaded a software from a site and want to install

Comment: Double click a .deb file to open it for installation in the Ubuntu Software Center. To install a .tar.gz file see: [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file).

Answer (score 0):

Please check your router and turn it off for 10 seconds and restart the router.
After that type `ping 8.8.8.8`.

If this works try to: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

if not do:
`ifconfig` to see your connection information it will properly be `eth0` and 
`sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0`
`ifconfig`

if you got an ip address then try: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

if not double check your router and connect the tcp/ip cable to to the wall and directly to your computer and type `sudo idown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0 && 
ping 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Can I use any other method to install software? I mean If I downloaded a software from a site and want to install?

Comment: yes what kind of file is it? .deb?